# Generated IPA is too small and I can't open it on my mac

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, azure-devops, ipa

I want to generate the IPA file for my iOS app and eventually distribute it via App Center.

Pipeline jobs:

```
steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: AppName.p12
    certPwd: password

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
    inputs:
    provProfileSecureFile: '17eaaz3c-9e96-4d1b-a52d-e400b94a2858.mobileprovision'

....

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/platforms/ios/AppName.xcworkspace'
    scheme: AppName
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: auto
    teamId: $(TEAM_ID)

...
// App center distribute job
```

The IPA file generated from the Xcode build has 3 MB and I can't open on my Mac (it says its from an unknown publisher). It also says that the Minimum OS is Android 11 in the Appcenter (Why is it saying Android instead of iOS?)

What am I doing wrong? Are there any other steps that I need to make?

Comment: The error might come from your mac. You can refer to [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5487056) to change your mac setting. BTW did you specify the `SDK` variable in your pipeline? You can refer to [this blog](https://damienaicheh.github.io/ios/azure/devops/2019/12/05/build-sign-your-ios-application-using-azure-devops-en.html) to configure your xcode task.

Comment: I used the default pipeline value $(SDK). Do I have to link it so it'll appear in the YML?

Comment: The default value of `sdk` field of xcode task is $(SDK). You just need to make sure there is a variable named `SDK` in your pipeline(in the variables field of yaml file or the variables tab of the UI edit page.).

Comment: Looks like it didn't make any difference... it still runs the same process and the result IPA has also 3MB.

Comment: You can try run  `xcodebuild -showsdks` in a script task to display the valid list of SDKs. Then assign the Variable SDK to an available sdk. For example `SDK="macosx10.15"` for mac os